# How to use OpenAPI 3.0 response "links" in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm writing an Open API 3.0 spec and trying to get [response links](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/) to render in Swagger UI v 3.18.3.

Example:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test
  version: '1.0'
tags: 
  - name: Artifacts
paths:
  /artifacts:
    post:
      tags: 
        - Artifacts
      operationId: createArtifact
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/octet-stream:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
      responses:
        201:
          description: create
          headers:
            Location:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: uri
                example: /artifacts/100
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  artifactId:
                    type: integer
                    format: int64
          links:
            Read Artifact:
              operationId: getArtifact
              parameters:
                artifact-id: '$response.body#/artifactId'
  /artifacts/{artifact-id}:
    parameters:
      - name: artifact-id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: integer
          format: int64
    get:
      tags: 
        - Artifacts
      operationId: getArtifact
      responses:
        200:
          description: read
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

renders a link like this:

[image: Response Link Example]

Is this expected?  I ask because the `operationId` is exposed on the UI and `parameters` is shown as a JSON reference make it seem like something is not displaying properly. I would have expected a hyperlink or something to take me to the appropriate section in the Swagger web page that corresponds to the API being referenced by the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is how Swagger UI currently renders OAS3 `links`. Rendering of `links` is one of the things on [their OAS3 support backlog](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3641):

> **OAS 3.0 Support Backlog**
>   This is a collection ticket for OAS3 specification features that are not yet supported by Swagger-UI.
>   ...
>   [  ] Links can't be used to stage another operation
>   [  ] Link-level servers are not available for executing requests

Comment: Is there any OAS3 UI/Editor that supports links at the moment?

Comment: @Carlton If you mean displaying `links` in some meaningful/useful way - I'm not aware of any OpenAPI doc renderers that can do that.