# Swagger OAS 3.0.0 using links will not populate parameter of next operationId

Tags: authentication, hyperlink, swagger

I have tried to follow the OAS 3.0.0 link documentation at [Swagger.io][1]. However after returning a json object with an authentication token, I cannot extract this value and populate the next step with this value. I have written this Swagger YAML file which does not seem to error, but does not put a token in the dlAuth argument of the showOverview operation. How do I diagnose this error, how can I test the Json path to the token and can anybody identify any errors with this YAML?

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Test API
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
paths:
  /auth/login02?dlUser={dlUser}&dlPwd={dlPwd}:
    get:
      summary: Get login api token
      operationId: getLoginToken
      parameters:
        - name: dlUser
          in: path
          description: login user
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: "bob"
        - name: dlPwd
          in: path
          description: login password
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: "bobspass"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: JSON output from Login
          content:
            application/json:    
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Login"
          links:
            authToken:
              $ref: '#/components/links/AuthToken'

  /home/overview/home.overview?dlAuth={dlAuth}:
    get:
      summary: Get content for Overview page
      operationId: showOverview
      parameters:
        - name: dlAuth
          in: path
          description: login authentication string
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: JSON output from API
          content:
            application/json:    
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Overview"
components:
  links:
    AuthToken:
      operationId: showOverview
      parameters:
        dlAuth: '$response.body#/resultData/authToken'
      description: >
            The `authToken` value returned in the response can be used as
            the `dlAuth` parameter in `GET /home/overview/home.overview?dlAuth={dlAuth}`.
  schemas:
    Overview:
      type: object
      properties:
        result_status: 
          type: integer
          example: 1
        result_data:
          type: object
          properties:
            overviewId: 
              type: integer
              example: 2
            stateName: 
              type: string
              example: "home.overview"
            pageContent:
              type: string
              example: "<div>hello</div>"
    Login:
      type: object
      properties:
        resultStatus: 
          type: integer
          example: 1
        resultData:
          type: object
          properties:
            authToken: 
              type: string
              example: "081D3D749383BAAC27AB3BBBDB6D5575"
            userFirstName:
              type: string
              example: "bob"

  [1]: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [How to use OpenAPI 3.0 response “links” in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55839466/113116)

Comment: Sadly it does, so if the UI doesn't handle it, I guess I need to word it: "how is it done programatically" - I'm not sure what the point of these links are if they don't work in the UI